# Obtaining estimates for $|I(f)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $R >0$ and $R\neq 1$, set $I(f)=\int_{|z|=R}\frac{Log z}{z^2+1}\,dz.$  By obtaining estimates on $|I(f)|$ proves $I(f)\to 0$ as $R \to 0$ and also as $R\to \infty$.

Using $z=Re^{i\theta}$ and since $Log z = ln R+i\theta$ for $-\pi < \theta < \pi$.

$|I(f)|=\left|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\ln R+ i\theta}{re^2i\theta+1}iRe]^{i\theta} \,d\theta\right|\leq\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left|\frac{\ln R+ i\theta}{Re^{2i\theta}+1}iRe^{i\theta} \right||d\theta|$

If I'm not mistaken, we have $|\ln R+i\theta|<\ln |R|+\pi$.  On the bottom we have $|Re^{2i\theta}+1|\leq R^2+1.$

Putting this all together we get: $|I(f)|\leq \frac{ln R+i\theta}{R^2+1}R.$

As $R\to \infty$ or $R \to 0$ that goes to zero.  However, I'm worried that my estimates may be incorrect.

Comment: $$|\log R+i\theta|=\sqrt{\log^2R+\theta^2}<\log R+\pi\iff$$

$$\log^2R+\theta^2<\log^2R+2\pi\log R+\pi^2$$ and thus your evaluation's correct (we can safely take $\;R>>0\;$, say) in the numerator, **but** in the denominator it must be $$|R^2e^{2i\theta}+1|\ge R^2-1$$ which changes nothing (and don't forget the square power for $\;R\;$ )

Comment: So you foiled out the $\ln R + \pi$? I'm just making sure I'm cear on every step.  Also, why is it $R^2-1$ and not $R^2+1$.

Comment: Because in order to obtain the inequality $\;\le\;$ you must either make larger the numerator *or shorter the denominator* . I'm not sure what "foil out" means within this context.

Comment: Could you show me how to compute out the denominator?  I think I'm missing something.

Comment: :$$\frac{|\log R+i\theta|}{|R^2e^{2i\theta}+1|}\le\frac{\log R+\pi}{R^2-1}$$ since $\;|z-w|\ge |z|-|w|\;$

Comment: Ah I see now.  So $R^2-1\leq R^2e^{2i\theta}\leq R^2+1$.